# what `extends (() => Unit)` mean?

Tags: scala

What does following syntax mean? What is being extended, `Function1`?

```
trait AlarmHandler extends (() => Unit)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general `(T1, ..., TN) => T` is syntactic sugar for `FunctionN[T1, ..., TN, T]`, so `() => Unit` is syntactic sugar for `Function0[Unit]`.

So in your code `AlarmHandler` extends `Function0[Unit]`.